# Hidden Divs on Hotpoint maps

Tags: html, hiddenfield

Im trying to get a map similar to this for when you click on the region of the map a div appears to the right and shows you the closest stores in that region

http://www.kaiwakaclothing.co.nz/our-stores.php

I have been using this website below for the code;

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/

and have implemented using hotpoints in dreamweaver to do the following

http://www.colmanweb.co.nz/websites/betacraft/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=31

however I cannot seem to get different text or hidden div to appear for each region.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I managed to fix this problem

added

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function togglewai() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText2");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if (ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
}
// ]]>
```

the key was changing the name function toggle to togglewai